# Handling integers bigger than Long with Firebase and android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, long-integer

I am developing an app with Firebase, it is a game in which certain scores are shared between players and can grow without a limit. I tried storing them as a String, but then I could not order them with orderByChild for the leaderboard. How can I handle this problem?

Comment: Do you really need to store values with more than 19 digits? Is it humanely possible to reach that value in your game?

Comment: In documentation, https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order the orderByChild() should work if you store scores as strings. Use BigInteger in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the number as a linked list, with each node in the list representing each digit. Be careful with the order; putting the last number (the ones digit) in the list first, makes math with the linked list easier, while the other direction makes it easier to return the nodes in the list to a number on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

To store integers which are big in size java provides a `BigInteger Class` to handle those numbers. I will suggeat you to use that first read the concept and then try to findout what you exactly want!

Check this one [BigInteger](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/java_math_biginteger.htm)